# History of the Enneper Surface

Tags: differential-geometry, math-history, minimal-surfaces

I was just wondering whether anyone could tell me more about the Enneper surface and its history (why it is important historically in the development of mathematics), or where to go in order to learn more.

Also, while reading Wikipedia, I saw the term "Enneper-like surfaces" (for higher dimensions).  I was wondering what "Enneper-like" meant.  How "like" is it?  Is there a unique generalization of the Enneper surface for each dimension, and in what sense are these generalizations?  What theorems have been proven for these "like" surfaces, and why do we only know of specific examples up to seven dimensions?

Any more cool information that you would like to share would be appreciated too!

Comment: Choe's article can be downloaded from his department website. See references at  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enneper_surface Some good pictures at http://www.gang.umass.edu/gallery/min/

Comment: Thanks!


(Keep 'em comin'!)

Answer (score 1):

[image]                                                                                                                         The parametrization from complex variables seems most interesting, this is the Weierstrass - Enneper Parameterization.

$$ X(u,v)  =  \Re\left(\int { 1 - z^2} dz  \right)$$

$$\Re\left( { z - \frac{1}{3}z^3}   \right)$$

$$\Re\left( { (u + i v) - \frac{1}{3}(u + i v)^3 }   \right)$$

$$ u - \frac{1}{3} u^3 + uv^2 $$

$$ Y(u,v) = \Re\left(\int i({ 1 + z^2}) dz  \right)$$

$$\Re\left( i ({ z + \frac{1}{3}z^3})   \right)$$

$$\Re\left( i ({ z + \frac{1}{3}z^3})   \right)$$

$$\Re\left( { i(u + i v) + \frac{1}{3}i(u + i v)^3 }   \right)$$

$$ -v -u^2 v +  \frac{1}{3} v^3  $$

$$ Z(u,v) = \Re\left(\int { 2z } dz  \right)$$

$$\Re\left( { z^2 }   \right)$$

$$ u^2 -  v^2  $$

So we can represent the surface using the patch  $ (u− \frac{1}{3} u^3 + uv^2,−v −u^2v + \frac{1}{3} v^3 ,u^2 − v^2)  $
with $ u, v \in R $

See: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass–Enneper_parameterization

Comment: But how was that discovered?  Why was/is it of interest? What is so special about this surface of all possible surfaces, or even of all minimal surfaces?

Meanwhile, how does one generalize it into higher dimensions? What do such generalizations mean?

Comment: I think Enneper must worked with Weierstrass in the 1860's , but it can be used to produce a great variety of minimal surfaces.

Comment: The Enneper surface can be used to produce other minimal surfaces? How so?

Comment: No, the general form of parametrization was used by Enneper and Weierstrass. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Enneper

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense.